# Covariance of random variables of Dirichlet distribution

Tags: python, numpy

I don't find an implementation in the library I work with of covariance function:

[image: Covariance Dirichlet]

I give a try at implementing it in Python:

```
import numpy as np
def covariance_dirichlet(X,alpha):
  cov_list = []
  sigma = np.sum(alpha)
  for i in range(0,len(X)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(X)):
      if i == j:
        iter_val_num = np.multiply(X[i],sigma)-np.power(X[i],2)#**2
      else:
        iter_val_num = -np.multiply(X[i],X[j])#a*b
      iter_res = iter_val_num/(sigma**2)*(sigma+1)
      cov_list.append(iter_res)
  return np.reshape(np.array(cov_list),(-1,len(X)))
print(covariance_dirichlet([[0.2, 0.2, 0.6,0.8],[0.2, 0.2, 0.6,0.8]],[0.4, 5, 15,11]))
```

Does this look right? Can it be simplified?

Comment: This doesn't run. You've passed the wrong number of arguments to your function. I think you've probably mis-placed a bracket for your first argument.

Comment: Small bug in the method call, now it is ok

Comment: Notice that, whereas you pass chi into your function, the equation doesn't actually refer to chi at all. It is only based on alpha.

Comment: which chi you talk about, in the params there are X and alpha

Comment: The description has a stylised X which looked like they meant chi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this look right?

No, for a few reasons. Primarily, *X* doesn't actually appear in the definition for the equation, so it doesn't make any sense to pass it into your function. Also, `*(sigma+1)` is on the wrong side of the quotient.

> Can it be simplified?

Yes. Perform fundamental Numpy vectorisation.

```py
import numpy as np


def covariance_dirichlet_slow(alpha: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    sigma = alpha.sum()
    n = alpha.size
    cov = np.empty((n, n))

    for j in range(n):
        for k in range(n):
            if j == k:
                iter_val_num = alpha[j]*sigma - alpha[j]**2
            else:
                iter_val_num = -alpha[j]*alpha[k]
            iter_res = iter_val_num / sigma**2 / (1 + sigma)
            cov[j, k] = iter_res

    return cov


def covariance_dirichlet_fast(alpha: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    sigma = alpha.sum()
    alpha_coef = alpha/(sigma**2 * (1 + sigma))
    diag = np.diag(alpha_coef*sigma)
    square = np.outer(alpha_coef, alpha)
    return diag - square


def test() -> None:
    alpha = np.array((0.4, 5, 15, 11))
    expected = np.array([
        [ 3.88165899e-04, -6.26074030e-05, -1.87822209e-04, -1.37736287e-04],
        [-6.26074030e-05,  4.13208860e-03, -2.34777761e-03, -1.72170358e-03],
        [-1.87822209e-04, -2.34777761e-03,  7.70071057e-03, -5.16511075e-03],
        [-1.37736287e-04, -1.72170358e-03, -5.16511075e-03,  7.02455062e-03],
    ])
    actual_slow = covariance_dirichlet_slow(alpha)
    actual_fast = covariance_dirichlet_fast(alpha)

    assert np.allclose(expected, actual_slow, atol=0, rtol=1e-8)
    assert np.allclose(expected, actual_fast, atol=0, rtol=1e-8)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: could you explain the use of np.diag and np.outer in your fast version? also where are the two random variables on which you are applying the function? because covariance is about measuring the similarity between two vectors

Comment: also where should the input of the dirichlet function follow simplex ? I don't see alpha as a simplex distribution

Comment: `diag` and `outer` are equivalent vectorised operations based on the way that the indexing works in the definition for the equation.

Comment: It seems like your source is https://www.statlect.com/probability-distributions/Dirichlet-distribution (or at least excerpted from it). Your answers are there. It has full definitions for the alpha parameter to the distribution. If you have difficulty understanding this, consider posting on https://math.stackexchange.com/ .